# Visa renewal and working Visa

Tags: working-visas, france, student-visa, family

Am having difficulties with my visa renewal at prefecture Lyon France.
I am from Nigeria and my husband is currently doing his PhD in France, we both have a long stay visa for three years, My visa is a student visa because I was given admission to study French in Alliance Francaise for two months and that gives me right to work (part-time) At this point I want to renew and keep the student status, to enable me to continue my work. I was told my visa status will have to change from student to Visitor or wife visa and I will not be able to work. which visa can I apply for to enable me to work in Lyon France? because currently am no longer studying French

Answer (score 2):

(sorry I cannot do a "comment" in this stackexchange since I do not yet have the requisite score)

There are a few different ways forward, depending on whether your is husband under a "scientifique-chercheur" long-stay titre de séjour or a "étudiant".

If it's the former: 
http://www.rhone.gouv.fr/Demarches-administratives/Sejour-travail-naturalisation-et-echange-de-permis-de-conduire-des-etrangers/Chercheurs-et-leurs-conjoints

If it's the latter: 
http://www.rhone.gouv.fr/Demarches-administratives/Sejour-travail-naturalisation-et-echange-de-permis-de-conduire-des-etrangers/Etudiants-et-leurs-conjoints

I know they're both in French, but Google Translate does a pretty good job on these pages.

Please do clarify your husband's situation so that we could provide you with a more appropriate response.

But in theory, you should be able to get a titre de séjour with the same time limitations as your husband's, on the basis of your relationship with him.

Edits:

Normally, once you need to apply for renewal (at least 2 months before your current one expires) you should check out the list of documents required (that's why I am asking under what type of "titre de séjour" or residence permit your husband is under), and you will apply for a titre de séjour as a family member of a student or researcher.

Either way, both should technically allow you to work.

It is only the visitor titre de séjour that will not allow you to work.

Lastly: please note that there is a difference between a visa and a titre de séjour/residence permit. The former allows you to enter a country while the latter is what you get to reside past the initial validity of the visa. 
France issues an initial long-stay visa valid as a titre de séjour (the acronym is vls-ts) valid for 1 year for those coming here to study, for example, for three 3 years. This needs to be validated at the OFII in the first 3 months of your stay. Upon validation, you get a sticker in your passport that is equivalent to a titre de séjour / residence permit.

You are then required to request for the "renewal" of this vls-ts at least 2 months before the expiration. Upon renewal, you get the residence permit / titre de séjour in a card format.

Comment: We are married and we have our marriage certificate translated in French as required by prefecture. what visa will give the authorization to work part-time in France.

Comment: Please see my edits. I did understand that you are married. What I was asking for clarification for was on the type of titre de séjour / residence permit your husband is under (because PhD students in France get either a "student" titre de séjour or a "scientist-researcher" one). Also, as far as I know, long-stay visas in France are granted for only one year (which then need validation at the OFII office)...and you have to then renew it as a titre de séjour in order to stay for the next 2 years.